# How to get entity collection from context in code dynamically?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, entity-framework-4, wcf-ria-services

Suppose I have 2 tables : tab1, tab2, with EF and Wcf Ria service, there are 2 entity Tab1, Tab2 available at client side of domaincontext. 
Then I want to get the entityset dynamically in code, like

```
MyDomainContext.Entities("Tab1");
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

In your client side code you will have a reference, such as:

```
using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client;
```

Then you would load collections of your entities like so:

```
var ctx = new MyDomainContext();

ctx.Load<tab1>( _ctx.GetTab1Query(), LoadBehavior.RefreshCurrent, (op) => 
    {
      var data = op.Entities;
    } , null );
```

In the above code snippet your server side domain service has provided you with the GetTab1Query.

Comment: Thanks. In your solution Tab1 is hard-coded. I want Tabl can be a parameter, so that I can get different entityset like Tab1s,Tab2s,....

Comment: @KentZhou It is possible, but you need to code your DomainService yourself if you want to make that possible.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this in Kyle McClellan's code in his [ComboBoxDataSource](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kylemc/archive/2010/06/18/combobox-sample-for-ria-services.aspx). He takes a string parameter and calls an Operation (or Query). This is now part of the [RiaServicesContrib](http://riaservicescontrib.codeplex.com) project in the ComboBoxDataSource module.

The essentials (from ComboBoxDataSource.cs, Refresh method):

```
Type domainContextType = this.DomainContext.GetType();
MethodInfo operationInfo = domainContextType.GetMethods().Where(
    m => (m.Name == this.OperationName) && (m.GetParameters().Count() == this.Parameters.Count)).FirstOrDefault();

this.Operation = (InvokeOperation)operationInfo.Invoke(this.DomainContext, this.Parameters.Select(p => p.Value).ToArray());
this.Operation.Completed += this.OnInvokeCompleted;
```